# python replace substring in bat file

Tags: python, string

I have a bat file in which I need to replace a substring in. The text I want to replace is contained within the following string:

```
this line has alot of text sim-manager-ui-38.05.00.00-THISHOT-other-stuff
```

The part that I want to replace is `38.05.00.00` as it is going to be a different value per the users request. This number will be provided by the user. Then I also want to delete the the `'THISHOT'` portion after the number has been replaced.

How can I go about both replacing the number value and deleting the 'THISHOT' portion? For example, if I wanted the number 40.00.00.00 I would want that line to read as follows:

```
this line has alot of text sim-manager-ui-40.00.00.00-other-stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find and replace that part using regular expression

```py
import re
import random

def pattern():
    return ".".join( str(x) for x in( random.randint(10,99) for i in range(4)) )

s = "this line has alot of text sim-manager-ui-38.05.00.00-THISHOT-other-stuff"

# If you want to only remove -THISHOT part you can: 
print(s.replace("-THISHOT", ""))

# If you want to replace that number pattern with another random number:
output = re.sub("(\d\d.*)*-THISHOT", pattern(), s)
print(output)
# this line has alot of text sim-manager-ui-12.56.81.14-other-stuff
```

Comment: How do I replace the number portion with another number?

Comment: @Dmango Do you want it to following same pattern, but the numbers are random?

Comment: I want to replace the number portion with another number in the same format, but remove the '-THISHOT'

Comment: @Dmango I updated the script. As I understood, you want those numbers to get new random values.

Comment: not quite. I edited my original post to show what I want.

Comment: @Dmango then you can simply remove `-THISOT` part with `s.replace("-THISHOT", "")`

Comment: its not a random number. its a user defined number as mentioned in the post.